# UITextField textAlignment Center

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, alignment

Here is my code and i want to change font size to the view width and i'm changing but **alignment distorted.**

```
func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool
{
    inputText.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignment.Center
    inputText.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignment.Center
    inputText.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
    inputText.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true

    return true
}
```

Comment: Did you try `NSTextAlignment.Justified` ? May be easier to use.

Comment: Yes. But same @KIDdAe

Comment: Why are you calling all this in the `textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:` method?

Comment: Because i need to when i entered a character @Bluehound

Comment: did you set the delegate for `inputText`?

Comment: how is the alignment distorted?

Comment: here is a screenshot http://postimg.org/image/ai240m4mt/ @rakeshbs constantly shifting left

Comment: This is probably because the font size doesn't go below a particular limit   and there is no room in the textfield to show the rest of the text. you can write a manual method to reduce the size lower than that.

Comment: Actually red area is textfield and i've tried manual calculating before but not again. So i'm resize font size to with but alignment distorted @rakeshbs